# Зависания в requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Получаю ответ от ВК API следующей строкой:

```
message_content = str(req.post(hg, data, timeout=2).content)
```

Но на этой (точно здесь) код зависает, таймаут не срабатывает. Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался? Найти подобное не могу, вот и спрашиваю здесь.

Пример hg:

`https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?`

Пример data:

```
{'message': '1 = 1.0', 'user_id': xxx, 'attachment': '', 'v': '5.62', 'access_token': 'xxx'}
```

Что самое интересное, код зависает примерно 1 раз из 7. При этом, он делает может посылать как одинаковые, так и разные запросы. Может быть проблема со стороны ВК?

Comment: Лучше: `req.post(hg, data, timeout=2).json()`, либо `req.post(hg, data, timeout=2).text`. А может ли у вас быть выше `message_content` обработка исключений, да и в цикле? Я бы еще поразбирался где именно проблема: при выполнении `req.post` или при `str(.. .content)` А чем `vk-api` не нравится? Он очень простой и удобный, я на нем кучу всего [писал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/vk_api__examples) (и внутри копался) и могу сказать, что он упростит работу с вк

Comment: отбросьте `.content` (это пытается читать весь потенциально бесконечный ответ). Попробуйте меньший timeout (полный timeout может быть больше в несколько раз). В сторону: никогда не вызывайте `str(bytes_object)`.

Comment: @gil9red Обработка исключений есть, но вне цикла. Как я понимаю, если таймаут произойдёт, то как раз появится исключение? Оно не появляется( Скрипт на этой строке зависает на ~90 сек (дальше весь поток убивается). То, что вы написали попробую сделать. Спасибо

Comment: @jfs поток завершается через ~100 секунд выполнения, за это время ответ не отправляется (это к слову о том, что полный таймаут может быть больше в несколько раз). А то, что вы описали я попробую сделать. Спасибо за советы